# Python While loop not looping

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, input, while-loop

I am trying to get user input with error checking using a `while` loop to make sure the user always enters something with more than 2 characters. However the *Python* program never asks me for input. Help?

```
first_names = ['fred', 'bob', 'mary', 'john', 'frank', 'james', 'joe', 'jay']
last_names = ['jones', 'smith', 'doe', 'cardinal', 'jesus', 'watson', 'blogs', 'harris']
full_names = ['empty_name']*len(first_names)
i = 0
while True:
    full_names[i] = (first_names[i] + " " + last_names[i])
    print full_names[i]
    i = i + 1
    if i == (len(last_names) + len(first_names))/ 2:
        True = not True
name = 'placeholder_name_for_user_input_via_console'
while True:
    name = raw_input("please enter a new name")
    if len(name) < 2 :
        print " please enter a name longer than 2 characters"
    else:
        True = not True
print "thank you for entering a long name"
full_names.append(name)
print(full_names)
```

I'm using Python 2.7 if that makes any difference.

edit:
I fixed my code. After the first while loop = need to write `True = not False` to make it work.

Comment: `True = not True` ...are you attempting to rip a hole in spacetime itself?!

Comment: should i use True = False instead?

Comment: @JamesWat no, you can't change the value of `True` just like you can't change the value of `1`

Comment: the first loop work, this is my output: fred jones
bob smith
mary doe
john cardinal
frank jesus
james watson
joe blogs
jay harris
thank you for entering a long name
['fred jones', 'bob smith', 'mary doe', 'john cardinal', 'frank jesus', 'james watson', 'joe blogs', 'jay harris', 'placeholder_name_for_user_input_via_console']

Comment: @AdamSmith: FWIW in Python 2 you *can* change the value of True, so the comparison with changing 1 doesn't quite fit.  It wasn't until 3 it was promoted from a standard name to a keyword.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed my code. After the first while loop i need to write `True = not False` to make it work:

```
first_names = ['fred', 'bob', 'mary', 'john', 'frank', 'james', 'joe', 'jay']
last_names = ['jones', 'smith', 'doe', 'cardinal', 'jesus', 'watson', 'blogs', 'harris']
full_names = ['empty_name']*len(first_names)
i = 0
while True:
    full_names[i] = (first_names[i] + " " + last_names[i])
    print full_names[i]
    i = i + 1
    if i == (len(last_names) + len(first_names))/ 2:
        True = not True
name = 'placeholder_name_for_user_input_via_console'
True = not False
while True:
    name = raw_input("please enter a new name")
    if len(name) < 2 :
        print " please enter a name longer than 2 characters"
    else:
        True = not True
print "thank you for entering a long name"
full_names.append(name)
print(full_names)
```

Comment: The syntax you used does not throw any exception, however the logic of your answer is wrong and rather dangerous. A correct and acceptable answer has already been given to your question, follow it. Gosh, its only good thing is to make one understand better the functioning of booleans in Python 2.x and trigger thoughts about how to fix messed up True-False variables!

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the value of `True`. `True` is the `True`est thing. Instead use `break`.

```
while True:
    full_names[i] = (first_names[i] + " " + last_names[i])
    print full_names[i]
    i = i + 1
    if i == (len(last_names) + len(first_names))/ 2:
        # True = not True; some_int / 0
        break
```

`break` exits the innermost loop it's found in.

Comment: Actually in Python2, you can reassign `True`. There is certainly no reason to ever do it though

Comment: @JohnLaRooy-AKAgnibbler what?! Holy crud that sounds like it would break things.

Comment: yes - the first loop will exit, but the second will be skipped because  it's basically a `while False:`